# How do you highlight the active page in your header using bootstrap3 and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to take this time to post something that would have helped me greatly and saved me hours of time if an article such as this existed on Stack Overflow. I was advised to post this as a question and answer my own question.

**The Problem:**
I wanted to have a navbar using bootstrap 3 that would recognize the page I was on and highlight the correct tab in the header. I tried many things, including creating functions that use file paths, file names, and more. Because of my project, I couldn't get anything to work. I also hit a point where I was able to highlight the tab I clicked on, but it would no longer switch pages.

I will post my solution as an answer to my own question. **If anyone has a better way of sharing my strategy with the community, please feel free to point me to the proper place and I will move my information.**

Comment: Please provide constructive feedback before down voting so I may improve my posts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the header.php file, this is the code that I used to create my navbar and effectively highlight the correct tab using nav-pills from Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
             <li <?php if($current == 'home') {echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $scfg_baseurl ?>/index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li <?php if($current == 'order') {echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $scfg_baseurl ?>/order_manager/index.php">Order Online</a></li>
            <li <?php if($current == 'about') {echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $scfg_baseurl ?>/about_us/index.php">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="OrderOnline">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AboutUs">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then, on each page I wanted to load in the navbar (Home, Order Online, About Us), I added the following **BEFORE** session_start();

```
$current = 'home';
```

or

```
$current = 'order';
```

or

```
$current = 'about';
```

depending on the page I was on so I could appropriately reference it in the header file. By assigning current to the name of the page I am interested in before the page loads, I was able to properly highlight the appropriate tab in the navbar.

I hope this helps someone out as much as it would have helped me.

I would like to credit [Team Tree House](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/how-to-highlight-the-current-pages-menu-link-so-the-user-knows-what-page-they-are-on) for posting this article that lead me to the resolution of my problem.

Feedback is welcome.